# If the test charge is dropped, how about the electromagnetic field? It is still there or disappear?

Tags: electromagnetism

When we put a test charge we can found the electromagnetic field there. This is clear. However when the test charge is taken a way, what about the electromagnetic field? If the electromagnetic field is a mutual energy phenomena or a interaction between the source charge and the test charge, when the test charge is dropped. The electromagnetic field should be disappear. If the electromagnetic field is property of the source charges. The source charge is there the electromagnetic field still there. I am confused. It seems the field is only an ability. The ability if a test charge appear there is a force can act on the test charge. But if the test charge is not there, we still do not clear whether or not the electromagnetic field is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The field is a property of space and the test charge is assumed small so it's effect on the source of the field is negligible. The force would be a mutual phenomenon, field is not. The field doesn't care about the test charge.

Comment: When the test charge is here, it is clear that the field can be test as true. How ever who knows what happens if the test charge is not here. And the test charge cannot be infinite small. It  is at least one charge. The force to the test charge depended to the potential, which is related to 1/r, where r is the distance between the charges produce the electromagnetic field and the test charge. Hence the force to the test charge always related to the position of the test charge. Hence the electromagnetic field should always related to the test chare.